# How to access attribute in a relational database PHP (Yii 1.1)

Tags: php, postgresql, yii

I am tasked to change the database and access some of the attributes of a new table.

I have created the table "tag" as well as a table in between called "dashboard_has_tag" as the tables "dashboard" and "tag" are in a many-to-many relationship to each other.

Now I need to know, how I can access the attributes (namely the tag as well as idtag) from a view. I have instantiated the model (dashboard) already. Is there a way to do this?

Here is a picture of the tables with the relations

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yii makes this rather easy. By using `$model->table_name->column`, you can access items in the related tables, as long as the models are setup for this. For instance, to access from dashboard to tag and idtag, `$dashboard->dashboard_has_tag->tag->tag` should get you the tag's text, and similarly, `$dashboard->dashboard_has_tag->tag->idtag` should get you the tag's ID.

If you use Gii to create your models, they should be setup for this.